# I can't define a value for students because of TypeScript error Type '{ Id: number; Name: string; }' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't define a value for students because TypeScript says it can't be used as index type. Note: I declared id as number not Number and Name as string not String.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
interface student {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'sameh-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  students: Array<student> = [];
  color: string = 'color: red';
  color2: string = 'color : blue';
  userName: string = '';
  title = 'ng-arab';
  constructor() {
    this.students[{ Id: 0, Name: 'sameh' }];
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is bad in "this.students[." Your code must be "this.student.push(your object)" or "this.studen[0] = your object" inserting that object en first position of your students array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to push an element inside the array on the constructor, change your code to.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
interface student {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'sameh-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  students: Array<student> = [];
  color: string = 'color: red';
  color2: string = 'color : blue';
  userName: string = '';
  title = 'ng-arab';
  constructor() {
    this.students.push({ Id: 0, Name: 'sameh' }); // <- changed here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
interface student {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'sameh-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  students: Array<student> = [];
  color: string = 'color: red';
  color2: string = 'color : blue';
  userName: string = '';
  title = 'ng-arab';
  constructor(enter code here) {
    this.students[{ "Id": 0, "Name": 'sameh' }];
  }
}
```